# How can I convert List<ViewHolder> to JSON and send to server by POST request

Tags: java, android, json, post

I have **List < ViewHolder >** data :

```
private List<ViewHolder> pizza = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();
        pizza.add(new ViewHolder("7", "Наполеон"            ,"bu salad3","25300"));
        pizza.add(new ViewHolder("7", "Дьяволо"             ,"bu salad3","25300"));
        pizza.add(new ViewHolder("7", "Карбонара"           ,"bu salad3","25300"));
        pizza.add(new ViewHolder("7", "Кольцоне прошуто"    ,"bu salad3","25300"));
        pizza.add(new ViewHolder("7", "Питта"               ,"bu salad3","25300"));
        pizza.add(new ViewHolder("7", "Гавайская"           ,"bu salad3","25300"));
        pizza.add(new ViewHolder("7", "С ветчиной"          ,"bu salad3","25300");
        pizza.add(new ViewHolder("7", "Пепперони"           ,"bu salad3","25300"));
```

How can I send this list data with JSON to server by POST request.

Sorry, If I wrote with mistakes, because my english is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override `ViewHolder.toString()` and let it return the string that represent the JSON. For instance

```
  @Override
    public String toString() {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("id", idField);
            obj.put("name", name);
            obj.put("price", price);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.toString());
        }
        return obj.toString();
    }
```

if you are using the HttpClient from Apache, you can use StringEntity and then you can set it as Entity for your post request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to send post: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139.

You will want to create a JSONObject and then call toString() on it to place it into the post data for your request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something solid to organize all your communication layer checkout [Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) , then you can easily implement in a transparent way all what you need [example of POST in JSON](http://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e435)